# I installed wget into my local directory because the system-wide wget was out-of-date. How do I use my updated wget instead of system-wide?

Tags: linux, wget, software-rec

I have a directory on a computer (used by my entire department) that has out-of-date wget software (wget-1.14). I installed a new version into my local directory, where I have write permissions (I'm not the administrator), using:

```
curl -O http://ftp.gnu.org/gnu/wget/wget-1.21.tar.gz
tar xvf wget-1.21.tar.gz
cd wget-1.21
./configure --prefix=/home/my/directory --with-ssl=openssl
make
make install
```

These commands seemed to work. But "`whereis wget`" returns the old software. Similarly "`wget -V`" returns "wget-1.14."

How do I use the newer wget-1.21 that I installed in my local directory?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can add in your login script (on the end) command like:

```
export PATH=/home/my/directory/bin:$PATH
```

Or you can use absolute path to `wget`

```
/home/my/directory/bin/wget http://URL.....
```